# Catch click + shift event on the map in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

I tried to catch events:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  this.shiftKeyPressed = event.shiftKey;
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  this.shiftKeyPressed = event.shiftKey;
});
```

Then:

```
this.map.on('click', (evt) => {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      if(this.shiftKeyPressed) {
           // Click with shift
      }
    });
```

But it works unstable.

Comment: Can you elaborate how is this unstable?

Comment: Unstable it means someyimes works, sometimes not

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OpenLayers event `originalEvent` property

```
map.on('click', (evt) => {
  if (evt.originalEvent.shiftKey) {
    //
  }
}
```

or a condition function from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_events_condition.html

full build syntax:

```
map.on('click', (evt) => {
  if (ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(evt)) {
    //
  }
}
```

or imported as in https://codesandbox.io/s/popup-forked-jt75xb?file=/main.js